# Why php text appear if i dont even write anything?

Tags: php, mysql

look im making a login and im trying to display on screen after the cliking the login `your text`button "This email does not exist" but its showing without typing .
I just want the text "This email does not exist" to appear after I write the email itself in the text box and search the database.The text in the middle between the login text and login box.
[Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKpT1.png)

```
$sql = "SELECT  `email` FROM `utilizadores` WHERE `email`='$emaillogin' ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows == 0) {
   echo '<p>Email não existe na base de dados</p>';
}
```

I tried everything but its still showing